# Would a cheap DIY fitness hack to replace factory/ store bought exercise tool be valid on Life Hack?

Tags: discussion, support

E.g. Someone tried to build this DIY - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/89864/diy-dip-station

- Because they count it as Hobby, and not Home Improvement (Is not exercise just as important at a Desk for work or a Bath for hygiene?).
- Fitness SE also doesn't want it.

In my case, there's a much smaller Hand Held item I'd like to replicate;

- It seems more life hack-ish,
- I already have some ideas & solutions and "parts" on the subject.
- I was hoping some answers ideas to complement or share alternatives to my Hacks

Could it be posted on Life hack?

**Item to DIY**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT3Gm.jpg

I'll write up some of my ideas with question if its allowed.

Would something in DIY make of store bought item count as Life Hack valid?

Answer (score 2):

There exists the tag [substitute-tool](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitute-tool) which is used for hacks that replace tools with something home-made.

You would have to justify that the indian clubs in your picture are *tools*.  Simply asking "*How do I make a club?*" would almost certainly be closed as off-topic - not requiring a life-hack.  However, "*How do I make a tool to get fitter?", along with reasoning in the question body stands a good chance of being accepted.

You can but try.